# How to extract the ids from the 99th percentile of results for each day

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-log-analytics, kusto-explorer

I have a data set in Kusto and I would like to gather the `id`s from each day where their `latency` is greater than the 99th percentile for that day.

e.g I have a table like this:

| id | latency | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 23.4 | 1/2/2022 |
| c | 1.4 | 1/2/2022 |
| b | 25.6 | 1/3/2022 |
| d | 2.3 | 1/3/2022 |

and I want the result table to just be

| time | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1/2/2022 | a |
| 1/3/2022 | b |

where `a` and `b` come from the 99th percentile of latency times for those days

What I would like to work:

```
let 99p= T
| summarize percentiles(latency, 99) by bin(time, 1d);
T
| where startofday(time) == 99p.time
| where latency > 99p.latency
| project time, id
```

Thanks for any insight, pretty new to kusto

Comment: What is the desired result in case you have multiple ids per day?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz to list all the ids above the percentile for that day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// This is not a part of the solution, only generation of a sample data set
let T = materialize (range id from 1 to 1000 step 1 | extend ['time'] = ago(rand()*10d), latency = round(rand()*100,2));
// The solution starts here
T | extend day = bin(['time'], 1d) | as T2
| summarize percentiles(latency, 99) by day
| join kind=inner T2 on day 
| where latency >= percentile_latency_99
| summarize make_list(id) by day
```

| day | list_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-20T00:00:00Z | [298] |
| 2022-03-21T00:00:00Z | [642] |
| 2022-03-22T00:00:00Z | [200,504] |
| 2022-03-23T00:00:00Z | [726,885] |
| 2022-03-24T00:00:00Z | [590,975] |
| 2022-03-25T00:00:00Z | [107] |
| 2022-03-26T00:00:00Z | [836] |
| 2022-03-27T00:00:00Z | [68] |
| 2022-03-28T00:00:00Z | [527,859] |
| 2022-03-29T00:00:00Z | [172,874] |
| 2022-03-30T00:00:00Z | [274] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1VQy2rDQAy8G/wPc4tdDLFzMyX9Ct9KCUpWSbbdh9lVaFPy8dWWPFrYg3ZGmhlpucR0tBn6QhQQZkqCuIccGTm6k9gYOsTgzjhw4EQFKA2ETH52DEOiNUtdORZMWMOTcLLk7DejSRQODGuwT9FjgEQMfd8jC8/6vYC/hIPB60Ks58WbztMhljHTtE9Db9oOTgXD7qxUiifF72Tfrdr2ua6WZY1HYBXXNTKOnLiupoeJoSKytaG52XUYTKsNlDGt6uqCfPKeUok%20c9pxEOs4N9cEHcaxxfZchErze7QBHzaYtQ16HJXQU/26FPaz%20N/Dv6z/KG6u6GYc/5t6%20lDSZmmsuTn9AG3io8elAQAA)